# Finding a radio button on activation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When radio button 1 is selected print hello 1, when radio button 2 is selected print hello 2. How do I do this?

```
<form name="form" id="form">
First Class<input name="seat_class" id="a1" type="radio" value="First Class">
        Second Class        <input name="seat_class" type="radio" value="Standard Class"
        </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to submit the form, or you want the output on the same page?

Comment: NO i dont want to submit the form, what i want to do is , if i select radio button 1, then i have to print hello msg, or else if i select radio button 2 , it sholud say bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radio1, #radio2").change(function(event) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($(this).data("text"));
        }
    });
});

</script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="test" data-text="hello 1">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="test" data-text="hello 2">
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make some change in your html :

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    First Class
    <input name="seat_class" id="a1" type="radio" value="First Class" />

    Second Class
    <input name="seat_class" type="radio" value="Standard Class" id="a2" />
    <!-- Adding id="a2" -->
</form>
```

And, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), add an event:

```
$(function () {
    $('#form>input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
            case 'a1':
                alert ('Hello 1');
                break;
            case 'a2':
                alert ('Hello 2');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the result :
http://jsfiddle.net/GPwXs/1/

Comment: switch($(this).attr('id')) to save you some repeat calling, and improve the code appearance to boot...

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to mention that this code requires jQuery in order to function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if you want to check if the radio buttons are pressed? or you want to perform an action when the user turns on one of the radio's, either way:

You can check if either radio is selected by returning only 'selected' buttons:

```
first  = $('#a1:selected');
second = $('#a2:selected');
```

To perform an action when selecting the radio:

```
$('#a1').change(function() {
  alert('foo');
});

$('#a2').change(function() {
  alert('bar');
});
```

Comment: But i am not able to do the same with select box.That Means if  i select window seat it should print window seat or if i select aisle seat it should print aisle seat..                              <select name="seat_type" size="1" style="width:200px;">
<option value="Window Seat" selected>Window Seat</option>
<option value="Aisle Seat">Aisle Seat</option>
</select>

Comment: @user760946: See how that's a question you just asked, and how it isn't got anything to do with this question?  You should ask it as another question (or, better still, search the old questions, as that's been answered before).

Answer (score 0):

@user760946. I think this is what you are looking for .. [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/GjbXG/)